# How to auto reload dialog content via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this function to open dialog box via ajax :

```
function gps(uid) {

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "file.php",
  data: {},
  success: function (data) {
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){

    $('#gps').html("Data : "+data[i]['latitude']+"");

    }
  }
});

 $('#gps').dialog('open');
return false;
}
```

How can i dynamically change the content of opened dialog box like every 1 second without closing the dialog box?

Comment: Dont use `setInterval`, what happens when the PHP script takes longer than a second @GuruprasadRao ? Use `Deferred Objects`

Comment: Yea!! I forgot to mention that part!! @Daan

Comment: i know about interval. But how i do implement it with the current code i have?

Answer (score 0):

```
 setInterval( function()
 { 
    gps(uid); 
  },1000);    
var loading_progress = false;

     function gps(uid) {
 //stop queue callbacks         
 if ( loading_progress )   return;        
loading_progress = true; 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    data: "data="+uid,
    async: false,  
    cache: false,
    success: function (data,status) {   
      if( ( status == "success")    { 
      var i; 
       for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){

        $('#gps').html("Data : "+data[i]['latitude']+"");
   loading_progress = false;

          }
    }
  });

 $('#gps').dialog('open');

}
```